# MySQL response times spiking at regular intervals

Tags: mysql, django, apache, database-performance, newrelic

I recently set up a windows Hyper-V VPS with a bitnami django stack. I am monitering the website with newrelic. I noticed that my MySQL database response times spike about every 30 min. My first thought was that a cron job was running every 30 mins, but there are no crons on this server. So I have two questions:
In newrelic what is "Other - SQL" field?
What could be causing the database response time to spike?

[image: Newrelic database performance]
<sub>(source: [troll.ws](http://i.troll.ws/5bc7b010.PNG))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In New Relic's Python Agent "OTHER" is given to any sql call that is not one of the following:

```
'delete'
'insert'
'update'
'create'
'drop'
'call'
'show'
'set'
'exec'
'execute'
'alter'
```

For information about the root cause of the spike you should open a support ticket with New Relic at https://support.newrelic.com